# Spring Security SAML Global Logout not sending saml response to IDP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I created my SP using Spring SAML Security. I'm having an issue with Global logout. The logoutRequest is sent to IDP and IDP sends back the logoutResponse. SP validates the message successfully and the logout.jsp is reached without a problem. 
The problem I'm having is that the IDP is expecting a “SAML Response” from the SP after successful logout to clear the session. Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SP is not supposed to send any additional response once it receives LogoutResponse from IDP. See [saml2-profiles, chapter 4.4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) for details. It also contains a nice picture which illustrates the message exchanges.